# C# Open multiple files in a single instance

Tags: c#, windows-installer, file-type

I have a Windows Form application. Using the installer it registers some costume file types so the explorer knows how to open these files when double-clicked. I also added code in the application to check if other instance of the application is already running. If so it will open the file in the same instance instead of using a new one.

However, I still have a problem. If the user selects many files at once and opens them Windows will start many instances of the application. Somehow the instance detection doesn't work at this moment and I will end with many instances of the application, each with single file loaded.

I would like to have windows to pass the names of the selected files in a single command, such as:

```
<APPLICATION_EXE> --open_file <FILENAME_1> --open_file <FILENAME_2> ...
```

Is it possible to register the files types like this?

Comment: This is not possible.  You'll need to fix your "instance detection".  The WindowsFormsApplicationBase class know how to do this reliably.

Comment: I don't know what installer you're using, but MSI-based installs have support to have file association done for you in the install. You shouldn't need to write code to do it.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I will try to fix my instance detection code to work even on early phases of the application. I will update here if I come to solution.
PhilDW, I think you didn't get the question. The file association is already working. However windows opens one instance of my application for every file when many files are opened together. I'd like to have windows associate all the opened files in a single call my application.